# Error when trying to harvest farm in minswap

Tags: staking

I have a ADA-MIN farm on app.minswap.org, connected with a Nami wallet.
Since a couple of days the "stake" button switched into "migrate" button.

Since then I could either withdraw nore migrate. I aways receive the failure notice:
"Need additional 5000000 lovelace but only 2939420 lovelace is available to choose."

I put addionial >100 ADA in attached Nami wallet but the problem remains the same.

No clue, what do do anymore.. help is very welcome! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Did you wait for a while after sending additional ADA to your wallet? Sometimes it can take a while until the new UTxOs are picked up by the wallet/dApp.

Not sure but 5'000'000 lovelace sounds like collateral. Have you set up the collateral in Nami? (Open Nami > Click on the icon in the top right corner > Collateral)

Otherwise the MinSwap Discord might be the place to ask for help (and don't forget to come back here and post your solution).

Comment: It finally worked out - Thanks and shout out to @eddex♦!
Solution was to set up the collateral in the Nami wallet!

Comment: @jay2kay great to hear! Since you are new here I want to quickly mention that you can mark the answer as "accepted" so other people can see that this answer provided the solution for your problem.